# Given a space of 3x3 matrices and a subspace W, how to determine if there is a subspace such that $W \oplus U = V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let W be a set of matrices of the form
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    A & B & C \\
    B & A & B \\
    C & B & A \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
where A, B, C are real numbers and W is a subspace of V which is a space of all possible 3x3 matrices.Is there a subspace U such that direct sum of U and W generates space V?I'm not sure if such subspace exists.

Comment: Does $U=(V-W) \cup \{0\}$ work?

Comment: And are you sure that $W$ is indeed a subspace and not only a subset?

Comment: I'm still relatively new to linear algebra so there are some issues with terminology.$ W$ should be a subspace of $M_{3x3}$ (a linear combination of matrices from $W$ still belongs to $W$).What should a matrix from $U$ look like?

Comment: It doesn't have a known shape I think, it just can be anything other than $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    A & B & C \\
    B & A & B \\
    C & B & A \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @FareedAF The set $(V-W)\cup\{0\}$ is generally not a subspace. Your suggestion is wrong.

Comment: Yes your right, I just figured it out.  $$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    0 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix} + 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 2 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$ is not in $U$ even though each matrix is in $U$

Comment: And just to set the record straight, yes, $W$ is indeed a subspace. This can be verified directly, or noting that $W$ is the set of solutions of a (very simple) set of linear equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that there is such a $U$, actually a lot of them, is a general fact from linear algebra. You surely want an *explicit* such $U$.

You can take for instance $U$ as the set of matrices with zero in the first row.

Comment: But for $W \oplus U = V$ to be true, we must have $W \cap U= \{0\}$, right? The set you proposed doesn't undergo this condition

Comment: Of course it does. An element of $W$ which is also in $U$ must have $A = B = C = 0$, and thus is the zero matrix.

Comment: Oh yes, your right I read it "$0$ in the first entry"

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you know that $W$ is a subspace, you also know that a complement $U$ exists.

How can you determine it? You can use the fact that $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^9$. Using the common basis for $V$, the coordinate vectors of a set of generators for $W$ form the following matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
and you just need to determine a basis for the null space of the transpose of this matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
because for each matrix $A$, the orthogonal complement of the column space of $A$ is the null space of $A^T$.

You can see that the matrix is already in RREF form, so a basis for the null space can be determined as
$$
\left\{
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
\right\}
$$
Going back to matrices, you get the subspace $U$ spanned by the matrices
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$